# wp_force_remove_style' not found

Tags: php, functions, array

I have this error show up in my error_log.

> PHP Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_force_remove_style' not found or invalid function name in wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287

I will appreciate your advice as to how to fix this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have an action, but not the valid callback for your action.

For example,

You have somewhere following line:

```
add_action( 'some_action', 'wp_force_remove_style' );
```

But not have "wp_force_remove_style" function defined.

You have to have a function as following:

```
function wp_force_remove_style() {
    // Do you stuff.
}
```